# Examples about using the command 'nx exec'

Tags: nomachine-nx

Any examples on how to use `nx exec` command with NX framework?

I would like to run a command in command line which is similar to `nx exec --command RD D:\test1 -p commontests` but using `nx exec` always throws me the error ''' `nx exec` requires passing in a command after `--` '''. The documentation page [exec](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/exec) does not have examples

Answer (score 0):

I have got my answer at [root-level-scripts](https://nx.dev/recipes/other/root-level-scripts). Usage of the command `nx exec` is possible within package.json file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the doc is updated: https://nx.dev/nx-api/nx/documents/exec

not just root-level scripts, you can place nx exec in package.json of any project to leverage nx cache:

```
{
  "name": "myorg",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nx exec -- <command> [..args]"
  }
}
```

or you can run `nx exec` directly in the terminal:

```
nx exec -- <command> [..args] # runs the command in all projects
```